# How do I create a loop that display each category and its post count?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have a blog that I built with Jekyll. On the side bar I want to include a `nav` bar that list each category along with total number of posts for each. This is what I have right now:

```
<h2>Post Categories</h2>
<nav>
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    <h3><a href="/{{ category }}">{{ category }}</a> ({{ category | size }})</h3>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

I'm not on my computer that has Ruby and Jekyll installed so I can't build the site locally. But is this something that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Liquid docs for the *size* filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/size):

> Size: Returns the number of characters in a string or the number of items in an array.

Here's a full listing of the [available vars using Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables), including `site.categories`.

Instead of calling `size` on your `category` var itself, you need to call it on the last argument, which is where the array of posts are hiding:

```rb
<h2>Post Categories</h2>
<nav>
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    <h3><a href="/{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a> ({{ category | last | size }})</h3>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But can you tell me why `{{ category | | last | size}}` has two `|`?

Comment: Whoops! That's totally a typo :-) Good catch. Answer updated.